# Azure Blob storage Download

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am learning Azure, I have successfully uploaded and list files in my containers. When I run the code below on my home pc everything works fine, no exceptions, however when I run on my work pc i catch an exception that states:

Blob data corrupted. Incorrect number of bytes received '12288' / '-1'

The file seems to download to my local drive just fine, I just cannot figure why it works different on two different PCs, exact same code.

```cs
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("My connection string");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("ARCS.TXT");
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"c:\a\ARCS.txt"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to run this code while Fiddler is running and then share out the corresponding request/response from Fiddler? Please remove anything related to your account from the request/response.

Comment: Please do not share the response body as well. I only need to see the headers.

Answer (score 0):

May be your Organization's firewall is blocking a specific port. I have written a blog which discuss similar kind of port related issues. Will request you to verify once from that. http://nabaruns.blogspot.in/2012/11/common-port-related-troubleshoot-in.html

Regards
Nabarun

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

That is a weird issue. It's more weird becuase file gets downloaded properly even after the error. I would recomend you use [Azure storage explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) on both of your machines.

If Azure storage explorer works fine on both the machine then next step would be to check the SDK version on both machine. There are chances of such error with older version of SDK.

You may also want to try [Commandline Downloader](http://azureblobdownloader.codeplex.com/) to trouble shoot your issue.

Note - **Azure storage explorer** and **Commandline Downloader** are open source. If download through them works fine then you can download its code and debug through it also.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend trying CloudBlob.DownloadToFile or CloudBlob.DownloadToStream instead of CloudBlockBlob